# Manage jquery api getScript url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue on how to change the url location when I point the url to my local file. As of now it points outside and when I work offline the code won't work.

Code:

```
void 0 == e.fn.ajaxForm && e.getScript(("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://") + "urladdress.com/something.js");
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "point the url to [your] local file?" Can you provide more code?

Comment: like for example when I change the address to my local file like "localhost/sample-project/assets/some-files.js" .

Comment: Is there a web server running on your local machine? `getScript` loads "...a JavaScript file from the [web] server using a GET HTTP request..." (see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Comment: Thanks! I check that out.